# SegmentedButton in android 2021?

Tags: android

I searched online and found many which are not supported now in 2021.
The most relevant one for me was [this](https://github.com/ceryle/SegmentedButton). Unfortunately as soon I write `compile 'com.github.ceryle:SegmentedButton:v2.0.2'`
I get a warning **compile is deprecated**
and until I delete this line `compile 'com.github.ceryle:SegmentedButton:v2.0.2'`
I was unable to Sync Gradle.

I already tried `implement` in place of `compile` but I get this error

```
Could not find com.github.ceryle:SegmentedButton:v2.0.2.
Required by:
    project :app
```

So, I there any possible way to over come this issue or any other alternatives.

Here is my Gradle(Module):

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
}

android {
    compileSdk 31

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.abdx79.notifications_manager"
        minSdk 23
        targetSdk 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }


    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }

//    allprojects {
//        repositories {
//            maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
//        }
//    }
// Above line cause this error 
//Caused by: org.gradle.api.InvalidUserCodeException: Build was configured //to prefer settings repositories over project repositories but repository //'maven' was added by build file 'build.gradle'

}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.5'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.5'
    implementation 'com.github.ceryle:SegmentedButton:v2.0'
    implementation 'com.github.ceryle:SegmentedButton:v2.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

Gradle(Project, Top-level):

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.20"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Did you follow the rest of [the installation instructions](https://github.com/ceryle/SegmentedButton#gradle), particularly the part about adding `jitpack.io` to your repositories? You might consider editing your question and posting both your top-level and module `build.gradle` files.

Comment: @CommonsWare I did and I get following error : Caused by: org.gradle.api.InvalidUserCodeException: Build was configured to prefer settings repositories over project repositories but repository 'maven' was added by build file 'build.gradle'

Comment: The `allprojects` bit goes into the top-level `build.gradle` file, as a peer of your `buildscript` closure.

Comment: @CommonsWare Even after that in XML in could not load co.ceryle.segmentedbutton.SegmentedButtonGroup .its says Class referenced in the layout file, co.ceryle.segmentedbutton.SegmentedButtonGroup, was not found in the project or the libraries

Answer (score 3):

After searching stacks finally found it.
[Toggle button](https://material.io/components/buttons/android#toggle-button)

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonToggleGroup
    android:id="@+id/toggleButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button 1"
        style="?attr/materialButtonOutlinedStyle"
    />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button 2"
        style="?attr/materialButtonOutlinedStyle"
    />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button 3"
        style="?attr/materialButtonOutlinedStyle"
    />
</com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonToggleGroup>
```

**And it also supports only icons**

Comment: https://m2.material.io/components/buttons/android#toggle-button also here (the older M2 version)